# Toast not working (Android)

Tags: java, android, toast

When I run this method 
`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
 from another thread, the application falls to be working only from the onCreate, but 
`DebugText.setText(txt);`

works fine everywhere ... who else can help?

```
public void screenMessage(final String txt) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //DebugText.setText(txt);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `handler.post(new Runnable() {...}` I tried like this but did't works too

Comment: `DebugText.setText(txt);` DebugText - it's TextView (it's works fine)

Comment: Which class contains `screenMessage` method ?

Comment: @FarShaD `screenMessage ` in MainActivity

Comment: So why `runOnUiThread` if you're already on the main thread?

Comment: @FarShaD, cuz i'm call it, from assync task, another thread, but it's did't works too without ` runOnUiThread ` or `handler`

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Or is nothing happening at all?

Comment: Would you post `AsyncTask` code (where you call `screenMessage` method)? Even better `MainActivity` class !

Comment: @FarShaD sry, i can't past norm code there, this link on pastbin http://pastebin.com/wB6HANpR , I'm using okhhtp library

Comment: I have know idea how your code goes around but try to put some logs in `onResponse` body, maybe it's not called at all.

Comment: @FarShaD, onResponse work's fine, i can print in TextView,it's works, but if i printing in Toast, app is crashing

Comment: Your question is unclear, please edit your post and add all code you got plus your log otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution as below(it works everywhere for me):

```
public static void showToast(final Context ctx, final String msg, int type) {
    if (ctx == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(msg))
        return;
    final int toastType = type == Toast.LENGTH_LONG ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, toastType).show();
    } else {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, toastType).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some description to it.

Comment: `public static void showToast(final Context ctx, final String msg, int type)`     call it like this? `showToast(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);` or how i can get current Context?

Comment: I have this code in UITool.java, and also have a singleton application object，called like `UITool.showToast(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`. context can be MainActivity.this OR the singleton application object by `MyApplication.getInstance()` when i cannot get any other context

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed calling start try this

```
public void screenMessage(final String txt) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               //DebugText.setText(txt);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).start();
```